# iOS app testing; does iPad have to use same Apple ID as iOS developer program membership

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS development and to owning an iPad; I have an app which is running on the simulator and now I want to test it on my own iPad.

My iPad is registered with my personal AppleID but I want to enroll in the iOS developer program with a separate business AppleID. Will this be a problem when I plug the iPad into my MacBook and want to test the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No problem at all doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @mattigalloway answer but I will add some more informations here.

You may have to change your Apple ID from your iPad by going to settings->App Store
only if you want to test in-app purchase. By sing-out from and resign in with in-app purchase test user.

I hope that make it more clear for you.